# Generalized Sophomore's dream. Question about originality

Tags: definite-integrals, summation

A few months ago I derived a beautiful fact:

$$
\sum_{n=k+1}^\infty n^{k-n}=\int_{0}^{1} t^{k-t}dt~~~(*)
$$

for every natural $k$. Generally:

$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a^n}{(n+s)^n}=\int_{-s}^{a-s} \frac{a^t}{(t+s)^t}dt
$$

It is easy to prove. You just need to use the fact that
$$
\frac{1}{(n+c)^n}=\int_{0}^\infty \frac{t^{n-1}}{(n-1)!} e^{-t(n+c)}dt
$$
I know about Sophomore's dream, but even after a long search I didn't find fact $(*)$ in the literature. Please help me and answer, is it original or not?

(+ 1 edition) After some time I derived another generalization (the fact above is just the case with $b=0$):

$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a^{n}}{(n+c)^{n}} \frac{\Gamma(n+b)}{\Gamma(n)(n+c)^b}=\int\limits_{-c}^{a-c} \left ( \mathrm{ln}\frac{a}{t+c}\right )^b\frac{a^t}{(t+c)^t} dt
$$

(where $\Gamma(x)$ denotes the Gamma-function). Other sum is interesting too:

$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a^{n}\Gamma(n+b)\Gamma(n+d)}{n!(n+c)^{n+b}\Gamma(d)}=\int_{0}^\infty \frac{x^{b-1}e^{-x(c-d)}}{(e^x-ax)^{d}} dx
$$

Comment: It's not original. Look for Euler's Gamma function and you'll find that.

Comment: I think that you can prove that last line from $n!=\int_0^\infty t^ne^{-t}dt$ for $n>-1$ (this is basically the definition of the Gamma function) and doing some substitution. (To prove the equation I just gave, use integration by parts and induction.)

Comment: I know, how to prove it, I proved it myself. I just don't know, am I the first person, who did it or not.

Comment: @DanilKrotkov I have not seen this shifted/scaled version, but inasmuch as it is simply a shifted/scaled adaptation, I would speculate that your development is not, unfortunately, an original.  Is that all you need for now or was there anything about the development that you wish to discuss further?

Comment: @Dr.MV Do you know, where to find an article or a book with this fact in it? Did you see it online or not? Send me a link, please. (And sorry for my english, I know it is not good)

Comment: @DanilKrotkov As I said, I have not seen this development before.  I am only speculating that it has been developed before.  By the way, I know that you already derived it, but I added an answer herein with the derivation to possibly help others that see this post.  I gave your answer a +1 and added it to my favorites!  It is really a cool relationship.

Comment: Your English is generally good. Your main mistake is that you use commas too much. (Наверно Вы русский? Они люююбят запятые. :))

Comment: @KCd Да, я русский (можно догадаться ещё по корявой фамилии).

Comment: @ Danil Krotkov : I never saw your equation (*) in the literature. It is not mentioned in the paper https://fr.scribd.com/doc/34977341/Sophomore-s-Dream-Function which deals with a different way of generalization.

Comment: @JJacquelin Yeah, I read that article, it's interesting, but the way of generalization in it was not catchy. Exuse me, is it yours?

Comment: One can always generalize on various ways depending on the context considered. Your generalization is more in the context of relationships between integrals and series, which is of interest. In the referenced paper, the generalization is more oriented in the context of the definition of special functions. One could generalize even more, for example : $$Sphd(\alpha,k;x)=\int_0^x t^{k+\alpha t}dt$$ covering both previous generalizations. By the way, my first comment was not to compare the ways of generalization, but only to point out that your eaquation (*) was unknown in the referenced paper.

Comment: The pdf file is available here vixra.org/abs/1507.0051

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although the OP has stated that he/she has already derived the more general form of the so-called "Sophomore's Dream," I thought that it might benefit others to see the development herein.  So, here we go ...

$$\begin{align}
\int_{-s}^{a-s} \frac{a^t}{(t+s)^t}dt&=a\int_0^1 t^st^{-at}dt \tag1\\\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^na^{n+1}}{n!}\int_0^1t^{n+s}\log^nt\,dt \tag2\\\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^na^{n+1}}{n!}\frac{(-1)^n}{(n+1)^{n+1}}\int_0^{\infty} t^ne^{\frac{n+1+s}{n+1}x}dx \tag3\\\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{a^{n+1}}{n!(n+1+s)^{n+1}}\int_0^{\infty}t^ne^{-t}dt \tag4\\\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{a^{n+1}}{(n+1+s)^{n+1}}\tag5\\\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a^{n}}{(n+s)^{n}}\tag6
\end{align}$$

as was to be shown!

---

**NOTES:**

$(1)$

We enforced the substitution $t \to at-s$

$(2)$

We wrote $t^{-at}=e^{-at\log t}$ and used the power series representation for $e^x=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}$.  We also used the uniform convergence of the power series to justify interchanging the integral and summation.

$(3)$

We enforced the substitution $t\to e^{-t/(n+1)}$.

$(4)$

We enforced the substitution $t\to \frac{n+1}{n+1+s}t$.

$(5)$

We used the integral representation of the Gamma Function $\Gamma (z)=\int_0^{\infty}t^{z-1}e^{-t}dt$, which for $z=n+1$ is $\Gamma (n+1)=n!$.

$(6)$

We shifted the index of summation using $n\to n-1$