# Equality of definite integral and infinite sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, definite-integrals

The following appear, by numerical evaluation, to be equal

$\int_\limits{0}^1 x^x \, dx=\sum _\limits{n=1}^{\infty } (-1)^{n+1} n^{-n}$

Can anyone prove it?

Comment: [Sophomore's dream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore's_dream)

Comment: Write $x^x = e^{x\ln x} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (x\ln x)^n/n!$ and away you go ...

Comment: In [THIS ANSWER](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1348418/generalized-sophomores-dream-question-about-originality/1348513#1348513), I developed a generalized version of the expression of interest (i.e., Generalized Sophomore's Dream).