# What kind of function represents the Sophomore's Dream sum?

Tags: functions, summation

I came across the following sum while studying the integral of $x^x$:

$$\int_0^1 x^x \,\text{d}x = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^n} = 0.783430510712... $$

When I saw this, my first instinct was to think of the [Dirichlet Eta Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function):

$$\eta({s}) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^s}$$

However, the term in the exponent of $n$ is, itself, changing with the sum, so this can't be it. I tried looking at [other similar zeta functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_zeta_functions), but most of them had the same issue.

Is there a defined function that represents the former sum? I couldn't find one through my own research.

**Edit:**

(1) I now know that the official name for this sum is the [Sophomore's Dream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore%27s_dream). However, I am still wondering if there is a way to represent this function using a zeta function, or something else that is similar.
This question's previous title was "Is this sum a variation of a zeta function, or something else?"

(2) Another similar function might be the series expansion of the principal [Lambert W Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Asymptotic_expansions):
$$W_0(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-n)^{n-1}}{n!}, |x|<\frac1e$$

Comment: Isn't this related to Somos dream (I hope I remeber the name right) ?

Comment: @Peter  I've never heard of that before! Googling that didn't take me to any math-related links. What is that?

Comment: @Mailbox I don't think it's Somos, but it rings a bell, yes. (equating an integral to a sum with almost the same summand/integrand, and it magically works) Someone with a better memory than me will have the reference.

Comment: [This one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2007019/equality-of-definite-integral-and-infinite-sum)! [Sophomore's dream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore's_dream). Makes sense.

Comment: It's the Sophomore's Dream: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore%27s_dream

Comment: @Jean-Claude Arbaut Thank you! Now I'm curious as to if this Sophomore's Dream sum has a more generalized functional representation, similar to the eta function.

Comment: I have no idea. I have always seen this merely as a curiosity.

Comment: I know of a more generalized form for the integral in question, and its series expression looks sort of like a Zeta Function. However, it doesn't really answer your question.

Comment: @Accelerator I'll take that. You can leave it either as a comment or an answer.

Comment: I found [this](https://youtu.be/gVTh_vJp_o8).