# Relations between integrals and series like the one below:

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, terminology, online-resources

I know:
$$\int_0^1 x^{-x} dx = \sum_1^\infty k^{-k}.$$

I think this is startling and neat at the same time that it has a superficial 'obviousness.' (Though the proof is interesting.) I'm just looking for a search term that would get me to sources discussing these types of relations, and it's hard to ask questions in person during the lockdown. Thanks.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format, for future reference.

Comment: Your precise question is unclear. Please add more details about what you are asking.

Comment: This is a [Sophomore's Dream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore%27s_dream) integral.  I provided proof of a generalization thereof in [This Answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1348418/generalized-sophomores-dream-question-about-originality/1348513#1348513).

Comment: Are you asking for functions that satisfy $\int_0^1 f(x) dx = \sum_1^\infty f(k)$? It is trivial to produce any number of them considering that values of $f$ on $[0,1)$ and $[1,\infty)$ can be chosen independently. [Parseval's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval%27s_identity) produces integral=sum formulas of this sort more systematically.

Comment: Thanks for all the replies.  I think 'Sophomore's Dream' was the hook I needed.